# Importing variable from a different Python file containing self

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, class

I have two Python files. One calls the other and I want to take the value from the variable document into a different function of a different Python file.

*a.py*:

```python
class A:
def abc(object):
    self.document= 20
```

*b.py*:

```python
import a
def xyz():
    print(a.document)  // I need the value from document but there is an error.
    print(a.A.document)// I need the value from document which is 20 but it also gives me the error.
```

However, this gives me the error:

```python
no-member: Method
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please clarify what you want to do. ``a`` has no variable ``document``. Any *instance* of the class ``a.A`` has such an attribute ``document``. Is ``.document`` supposed to be the same for all instances? Should ``xyz`` work on a specific instance of ``a.A``?

Answer (score 1):

Do not see class initialisation in your question.

a.py:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.document = 20
```

b.py:

```
from a import A

my_A = A()

print(f"{my_A.document=}")
```

Comment: def __init__(self):    is already declared  and then there is another function , if that will work?

Comment: You have to *call* `__init__` in order for it to set the attribute.